# Android creating ordinary menu with ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have in my activity ActionBarSherlock action bar. It is created with method onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu). How to leave this menu available like actionbar and create ordinary menu with some buttons?

Comment: Do you mean, how to force the menu button to be in the actionbar on 2.3- versions of android?

Comment: I mean to create ordinary menu (which is invoked with menu button) along with ActionBarSherlock

Comment: It should be doing that already on older versions of android. To get it to do that on newer versions as well just compile against a target sdk older than honeycomb.

Answer (score 0):

Create a layout for your application. For example, create a button for your menu. And you can also use graphical UI android eclipse plugin to position it.

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/testButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="@string/testTitle"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In your activity class, which extends com.android.Activity,

```
Button testButton;

testButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.testButton);

        testButton .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            // Code to perform on click of the menu button
            }
        });
```

Comment: The question is not how to create a simple button.